# Babel polyfill with webpack

Tags: error-handling, webpack, babeljs, polyfills

Do I need to include `import "babel-polyfill"` to the top of each entry file, or is it enough to have `babel-polyfill` rule just in webpack.config file? I am confused by polyfill docs and still getting following error: `only one instance of babel-polyfill is allowed`

My webpack.config in short:

```
  entry1: ['babel-polyfill', 'homepage.js'],
  entry2: ['babel-polyfill', 'not-homepage.js'],
  entry3: ['babel-polyfill', 'contacts.js']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are calling multiple instances of the babel-polyfill.

You can choose any of the two option, but not both.

If you use webpack, don't put separate entries pointing to separate files, but rather point to a directory.

E.g: If your files are in app/js

```
module.exports = {
   entry: ['babel-polyfill', './app/js']
};
```

> If you decide to import it, make sure you import/require it only once
>   at the entry-point to your application, before anything else is
>   called.

Comment: Thank you! That is the problem I think... I have changed the entry point as you said (`entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/js/']`), but when running webpack now, an error shows up (`ERROR in multiple main`). Should I change the output filed too? Currently my output is:
`output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
      filename: '[name].js'
})`