# babel-poyfill in webpack multiple instance error

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-polyfill

I am getting a 'only one instance of babel-polyfill is allowed' Error when running a webpack compiled javascript file using the webpack config below.

```
const config = {
  entry: {
    file1: ['babel-polyfill','/path1/file1.js'],
    file2: ['babel-polyfill','/path2/file2.jsx'],
    file3: ['babel-polyfill','/path3/file3.jsx'],
    file4: ['babel-polyfill','/path4/file4.js'],
},
```

Note the problem only occurs for file4, the application was working fine using config above until I added file4 and its components (the only dependencies for these new components are React from react).

I then changed to:

```
const config = {
  entry: {
    file1: '/path1/file1.js',
    file2: '/path2/file2.jsx',
    file3: '/path3/file3.jsx',
    file4: '/path4/file4.js',
},
```

And included the following at the start of each of files1-4:

```
require("babel-polyfill");
```

But still got the same error 'only one instance of babel-polyfill is allowed' only on file4 (files1-3 didnt throw the error).

My question is similar to [Babel polyfill with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38118210/babel-polyfill-with-webpack) but my files are in different paths so I cant use a single directory as per the answer for this question. Any ideas?